# Filter and sort CSV data and store as PDF file with page breaks after specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pdfkit

I am using a Python script that imports CSV data, filters and sorts it, converts it to HTML and then PDF. I'd like to find a way to add page breaks after specific rows.

Assume the following example:

The data is sorted by columns `col1` forming "groups". I'd like to add a page break after every group (new value in `col1`):

*Input data (CSV table)*

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | a |
| A | y | b |
| B | x | a |
| B | x | a |
| B | y | b |
| B | x | a |
| C | x | a |
| C | y | b |

*Output data (table in PDF)*

(page breaks added, column headings repeated every page)

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | a |
| A | y | b |
| pagebreak |  |  |
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| B | x | a |
| B | x | a |
| B | y | b |
| B | x | a |
| pagebreak |  |  |
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| C | x | a |
| C | y | b |

My workflow briefly looks as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_filename, encoding="")

filtered_df = df[some_condition]

filtered_df = filtered_df.sort_values(some_other_condition)

html_table = filtered_df.to_html(index=False)

html_string = html_head + html_something + html_table + html_something_else + html_foot

pdfkit.from_string(html_string, outfile_name, options=pdfkit_options)
```

I see the following alternative approaches (but don't have a clue how to implement them yet, and I don't like any of them):

1. Parse the data and add "ghost" lines, carrying no data but some *magic string token* that can be replaced after the HTML conversion by other HTML magic (table row with specific CSS style?). Feels very hacky.
2. Split the big table into smaller tables (one for every group - but how?). Convert them to HTML separately and put them back afterwards (using some HTML/CSS magic).
3. Use some pdfkit option or `pandas.DataFrame.to_html` option I don't know about.
4. Use a completely different approach.

I don't know all the values `col1` holds in advance, but it's probably easy to find them out once and reuse them for further processing.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following approach (#2 of OP):

Split single table up into smaller tables ("sub tables") and converting them one after each other to HTML, putting all HTML tables together with page breaks in between.

1. Get unique values of the `group_column` (in my example that would be `col1`)
2. Iterate over the groups and filter the `pandas.DataFrame` to select only rows that match the group.
3. Add page break after every group/table (except after the last one).

   ```
    html_page_break = '<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>'

    groups = filtered_df[group_column].unique()

    html_string = html_head + html_note

    for i, group in enumerate(groups):
        filtered_df_subtable = filtered_df[(filtered_df[group_column] == group)]
        html_table = filtered_df_subtable.to_html(index=False)
        html_string += html_table
        if i < len(groups) - 1:
            html_string += html_page_break

    html_string += html_foot
   ```

The conversion from HTML to PDF is untouched.

Thanks @notarealgreal for `html_page_break` + `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
html_page_break = '<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>'
html_string = ''

html_tables = filtered_df.to_html(index=False)
for i, html_table in enumerate(html_tables):
    html_string += html_head + html_something + html_table + html_something_else + html_foot
    if i < len(html_tables) - 1:
        html_string += html_page_break
```

Then just like you do:

```
pdfkit.from_string(html_string, outfile_name, options=pdfkit_options)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by `enumerate(html_tables)`? `enumerate(html_table)` where `html_table = filtered_df.to_html(index=False)` or `enumerate(filtered_df)`? When using `enumerate(html_table)` I get a loop over all characters of the generated HTML. When using `enumerate(filtered_df)` I get a loop over the column names.

Comment: Just with the html_table